# PHP PDO Select result showing as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the (float) value from a database, but when I print the result it is showing as 'Array' instead of the value (20).

Here is the code:-

```
public static function getTourFare($fieldTour) {

       $pdo = new SQL();
       $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

       try {

           $query =   "SELECT Fare FROM tbltours
                       WHERE TourName = '$fieldTour'";

           $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

           $stmt->execute();

           $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

           $stmt->closeCursor();

           print_r($result[0]);

           return $result;

           $dbh = null;

       }

       catch (PDOException $pe) {
           die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
       }

}
```

I know it is only selecting one value and shouldn't return an array of values. I believe the issue is `$stmt->fetchAll();`, but I'm not quite sure what this needs to be changed to?

Comment: `float` is a number not `integer`.

Comment: Did you try fetchAll() manual entry?

Comment: fetchAll always returns a 2d array, even if there's only a single row... this isn't a bug in PHP, it's standard documented behaviour: `print_r($result[0]['Fare']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) documentation

> **`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`** returns an array containing all of the
>   remaining rows in the result set. The array represents each row as
>   either an array of column values or an object with properties
>   corresponding to each column name.

You can use [`fetchColumn()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to fetch just a string result.